# python sybpydb, sql with if else not working

Tags: python, sap-ase

I have a simple if else query

```
sql = "if ( exists ( select 1 from sysobjects )) select 1 else select 0"
```

when I execute it via python,

```
import sybpydb
conn = sybpydb.connect(user='xxx', password='xxxxx')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
rows = cur.fetchall()

print rows
```

I get

> sybpydb.DatabaseError: Error in fetching

However through isql/sqsh, the query run's perfectly

```
sqsh> if ( exists ( select 1 from sysobjects )) select 1 else select 0;

 -----------
           1
```

This is my Sybase version

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP01 PL01/EBF 24358 SMP/P/RS6000/AIX
>   6.1/ase160sp01plx/3663/64-bit/FBO/Wed Apr  1 07:56:01 2015

Python version is 2.6

The problem seems to be only with if else queries, all other queries are running fine

Please help!!!